# Trouble unlinking and deleting row on database using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I delete the first time, the unlink of the image works well and the row is deleted successfully from the data table.

The problem is that I'm using Ajax Jquery to request to delete and unlink the image so the page doesn't refresh and when I try to unlink and delete for the second time it doesn't have any response and the image doesn't unlink also the row isn't deleted.

Also, I'm trying to use a jquery data table to load the rows but it doesn't sync the data.

Ajax code :

```
var id = $('#deleteAdmin').data('id');

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>CRUD_Controller/crud_delete/" + id + "/administrador",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false, 
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data){


                        /*Func Ajax get admin without access*/
                        $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>CRUD_Controller/crud_getDataAll/administrador/administradores_null",
                            cache: false,
                            contentType: false, 
                            processData: false,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function(data){

                                $('#example2 tbody').html(data);

                            },
                            error:function(xhr)
                            {
                                alert('Algo falhou, nao caregou a tabela. - ' + xhr.statusText);
                            }
                        });

                        $('#atribuir').modal('hide');

                        swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
                            'Removido!',
                            'O administrador foi removido do sistema com sucesso.',
                            'success'
                            );

                    },
                    error:function(xhr)
                    {
                        alert('Algo falhou, carregue a página novamente. - Erro : ' + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

Controller functions :

```
public function crud_delete($id, $table_name)
    {
        switch ($table_name) {
            case 'administrador':
            $rows = $this->Administracao_model->getData($id, $table_name);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $imagem = $row->imagem;
                unlink(FCPATH.'assets/images/Administradores/'.$imagem);
            }
            $this->Administracao_model->deleteData($id, $table_name);
            break;
        }
    }

public function crud_getDataAll($table_name, $page_name)
    {
        switch ($page_name) {
            case 'administradores_null':
            $rows = $this->Administracao_model->getDataAdminSemAcesso($table_name);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><a href="#">#ADMIN' . $row->id . '</a></td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center">' . $row->nome . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center">' . $row->apelido . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center">' . $row->cargo . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><span class="badge badge-danger">Sem Acesso</span></td>';
                echo '<td class="align-middle text-center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-white btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-nome="'.$row->nome.'" data-apelido="'.$row->apelido.'" data-cargo="'.$row->cargo.'" data-contacto="'.$row->contacto.'" data-email="'.$row->email.'" data-imagem="'.$row->imagem.'" data-target="#atribuir" id="atrb"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            break;

            default:
            echo "Erro no contnroller.";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Models :

```
function getDataAdminSemAcesso($table_name)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('id_nivel', null);
        $query = $this->db->get($table_name);
        return $query->result();
    }

function getData($id, $table_name)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get($table_name);
        return $query->result();
    }

function deleteData($id, $table_name)
    { 
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($table_name);
    }
```

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you use an id or class when performing a delete process, you must call the function again to process the delete.

My suggestion is that you only delete rows without having to update the data in the table.

You can add id to tr, and deleted when the process was successful

```
var id = $('#deleteAdmin').data('id');

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "<?=base_url()?>CRUD_Controller/crud_delete/" + id + "/administrador",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        $("#"+ id).remove(); // Delete row
    },
    error:function(xhr)
    {
        alert('Algo falhou, carregue a página novamente. - Erro : ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to solve one issue changing the ID with a simple class instead of calling by the ID. So one more issue is still persisting... my DataTable is not syncing the data.
Any ideia?